# macOS: Import .p12 certificate into the keychain via command line

Tags: ios, bash, macos, command-line, keychain

I'm trying to import .p12 certificate into the keychain on my mac via bash script. So far, I've been trying:

1. `sudo security import` command. It returns that import was successful but, in fact, it never gets imported into any keychain.
2. `sudo  security add-certificates -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain certificate.p12`
   it throws the following error:

> Password:
> SecCertificateCreateFromData: Unknown format in import.

The only thing that worked for me was the .cer format via this command: `sudo  security add-certificates -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain certificate.cer`. It does import the certificate into the keychain and I can see it in the keychain access.

But I only have .p12 certificates. Could anyone help me with that one, please?

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked.

First unlock the keychain *(in lots of automated build systems it's just "")*.

```
security unlock-keychain -p "<keychain_password>" ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Second install the p12 file.

```
security import <p12_path> -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P "<p12_password>" -T /usr/bin/codesign
```

Answer (score 1):

The `security add-certificates` command can be used only to import certificates (such as .cer file, without the key).
To import a p12 keystore, the `security import` command have to be used.
Example:

```
security import certificate.p12 -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain -P 'keystore_password'
```